# Finding roots of complex equation, z in exponent

Tags: complex-numbers, roots

I'm trying to find the roots of this particular equation $z^3 +5 = e^{-z} $.

I started by setting $z = re^{i\theta}$, but got stuck immediately after. I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: It is unlikely to have closed-form solutions.  Are you sure that's what you need?  Are you asked to prove roots exist, or count roots in some region? Or will approximate numerical solutions such as $-1.19367457454506$, $0.810137625642755 \pm 1.50463921730091 i$ and $-6.31483411181355 \pm 5.22253624981830 i$ do?

Comment: I'm asked to find the number of roots that exist in the right half plane. In order to find that, I thought I had to find the roots of the equation. Is there a different way to approach this?

Comment: There are theorems for root-counting in complex analysis; see Rouche's theorem and the argument principle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simplistic manner could be first to plot the function
$$f(z)=z^3-e^{-z}+5$$ in the real domain. This shows a single root close to $z=-1.20$.

For the complex roots, in order to locate them, I should let $z=a+i b$. Expanding, the equation write
$$\Big[a^3-3 a b^2-e^{-a} \cos (b)+5\Big]+i\,\Big[3 a^2 b-b^3+e^{-a} \sin (b)\Big]=0$$ There is no way to eliminate $a$ or $b$ as a function of the other.

So, define
$$\Phi(a,b)=\Big[a^3-3 a b^2-e^{-a} \cos (b)+5\Big]^2+\,\Big[3 a^2 b-b^3+e^{-a} \sin (b)\Big]^2$$ and look at a [contour plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ContourPlot%5B%285+%2B+a%5E3+-+3*a*b%5E2+-+Cos%5Bb%5D%2FE%5Ea%29%5E2+%2B+%283*a%5E2*b+-+b%5E3+%2B+Sin%5Bb%5D%2FE%5Ea%29%5E2%3D%3D1%2C+%7Ba%2C+-2%2C2%7D%2C+%7Bb%2C+-2%2C+2%7D%5D). So, we see three of them, one being the real root. For the other, use Newton-Raphson method. Starting from the visual guess, the iterates will be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & z_n \\
 0 & 1.00000\pm 2.00000\, i \\
 1 & 0.84496\pm 1.62044\, i \\
 2 & 0.81112\pm 1.51297\, i \\
 3 & 0.81013\pm 1.50468\, i \\
 4 & 0.81014\pm 1.50464\, i
\end{array}
\right)$$

For the real root
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & z_n \\
 0 & -1.20000 \\
 1 & -1.19370 \\
 2 & -1.19367
\end{array}
\right)$$

For the two other conjugate roots, make another plot in the region of what @Robert Israel gave as answer (they are much more difficult to locate) and repeat the numerical procedure.